# Not able to register user using external login(google) using oauth apis

Tags: authentication

I am facing an issue with External login using google. We have login using google feature on the website

I have used this [blog](https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Integrating-Google-Sign-in-Asp.net-MVC#google_vignette) to implement google login. I am able to redirect the user to gmail on clicking the google login button on the sitecore website and receive the response(user profile) back in Sitecore.
But after receiving the response, I am not able to create user in sitecore as the create user method(`Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.User.Create(fullName, password);`) does not register the user without password. As this is external login so I don't have password. I just get name and email of the user from gmail

I don't want to use Sitecore federated authentication as I have to enable federated authentication in the Sitecore configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you might find a virtual user is more appropriate. You can create as below:

```
string domain = "external";

Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user =
    AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, loginInfo.Email), true);

AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(user);

this.Redirect(Context.Site.GetRootItem().Url());
```

Some useful references here:

- [Virtual User](https://www.kasaku.co.uk/2017/11/22/virtual-user-custom-properties/)
- [Getting started with virtual users](https://www.aharb.me/getting-started-with-sitecore-virtual-users/)